# Enable/Diagnose HDMI sound failure on Intel Bay Trail Atom Z3735F "Compute Stick"

Tags: linux, audio, acpi, intel-graphics, hdmi

I installed Debian Stretch (Kernel 4.8.0-1) multi-arch net-inst successfully to the eMMC, with Grub, and dual-boot to the original OS (where the sound does work).

Well, with half the peripherals. This question is about the HDMI-Sound. I tried:

```
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...

$ lspci
... Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0f)

$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set "audio" "on"
(Screen flashes once, but no change apart from `xrandr -q --props` output)

# dmesg | grep -iE 'audio|so?u?nd|sst|pcm|hda|hdmi'
intel_sst_acpi 800860F28:00: no matching machine driver found

# dpkg -l | grep -iE 'intel|nonfree' | awk '{printf $2" "}'
firmware-intel-sound firmware-linux-nonfree firmware-misc-nonfree i965-va-driver
intel-microcode iucode-tool libdrm-intel xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Grepping `-iE 'audio|sound|sst|0F28'` my decompiled ACPI DSDT [like described here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DSDT) resulted in 5 blocks of 3 lines with "Intel Audio" devices, including some with "HAD0F28 Intel HDMI Audio driver". The others are `80860F28, ADMA0F28, TIMC0F28, AMCR0F28`. Curiously, there also were 4 lines like `10EC5640 Realtek I2S Audio Codec`.

This is of these "HDMI Compute Stick Clones". Mine is from CSL, called "PC on a Stick", but there are many different re-branders of the same same Intel Bay Trail Quad-Core SOC platform. Mine is the fan-less variant without the separate audio-jack. This is one of those "32Bit UEFI with a 64Bit Processor" beasts.

There is a [`dsdt` acpi patch and a kernel patch from early 2015 floating around for a similar model](http://www.cnx-software.com/2015/05/08/minix-neo-z64w-intel-atom-z3735f-mini-pc-gets-hdmi-audio-in-ubuntu/), but I have not found out, if they apply to me, and/or whether they are already applied. (My UEFI Date is 09/2016, and my kernel is 4.8)

Another similar device seems to be the "Meegopad m1", and the ODM name seems to be "Quanta NH1". Mine has [a problematic Broadcom Wifi brcmfmac43430](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328001/trouble-activating-the-sdio-broadcom-bcm43430-wifi-chip-on-linux-4-8-0) though.

How get I get the sound to work, or where do I go from here?

Comment: In my dmesg output, the Intel HDMI shows up as something like `input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11`. Don't grep dmesg output for terms if you are not sure they'll be used. Instead, *read* the output.

Comment: @dirkt : There is no mention of either HDA, or HDMI  in neither `dmesg` nor `lspci`. Those I would have found and posted. I'll update the Q with that info. And rest assured, I have read/skimmed the entire `dmesg` output. And, yes, I am holding it correctly ;) . But thanks anyway

Comment: If nothing shows up in dmesg and `snd_hda_intel` is loaded properly, your kernel drivers don't detect the HDMI hardware. First step is to upgrade to the latest kernel. I'm also not sure detection works via ACPI, most kernel modules do their own detection (but of course it's possible that they use ACPI insome cases). In doubt, check the source.